# How to manage data bindings in a 100% custom grid control

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm writing a custom control from scratch (using `Graphics`) that will represent a set of columns each of which will have a list of cells, a lot like a grid view except this will have some custom features.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to manage all the data binding problem. I'd like this grid to have a `DataSource` property which would basically need to be a jagged array (2D) of some objects each of which would need to be bound to a cell in the control. I'm still not sure which properties each of these objects will have, and so far I'm only using text. What I've been trying to do is have my model implement this interface:

```
public interface IDiagramDataSource
{
    IBindingList Columns { get; }
}
```

and then have each column implement this:

```
public interface IDiagramColumnDataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    IBindingList Cells { get; }
}
```

But I'm still having a hard time figuring out the best way to keep all these objects synchronized to the corresponding objects in my grid. I'd love to be able to put all the binding mess in an independent class but not sure how to do this. For now I'll just repaint the whole thing whenever there is any change in the data source, but I'd like to eventually be able to identify which property in which cell or which cell in which column have changed so that I can update only the necessary items in my grid.

Is there any pattern to follow when you want a control to be bindable to nested lists? I'm guessing there is since the `DataGridView` control does this.

Comment: `a lot like a grid view except this will have some custom features.` - May I ask what these custom features are?

Comment: It will actually be like a flow diagram. Each cell will have an arrow that will point to the closest non null cell on the right (so it may expand on top of other columns). You'll be able to move cells up and down (not the whole row). And probably other things I still don't know.

Comment: `"it will actually be"` sounds like you haven't gotten too deep into this yet. Just a suggestion.. have you considered WPF for this? it could be MUCH easier to do such an advanced thing (from a UI perspective) in WPF that winforms

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 option:

First suggestion has been suggested by HighCore, is to using WPF rather than custom winform object to do the job. WPF also has much more controls (ListView, even the generic ItemContainer, if I am not mistaken). Just implement the INotifyPropertyChanged at the ViewModel, then call OnPropertyChanged for the root (aggregate) element everytime you need to refresh the control. Don't forget to add UpdateSourceTrigger for ItemsSource Binding. WPF controls also has good implementation for drag and drop function.

I won't detail the implementation in WPF since there are much articles explaining it.

However if you think that it must be done with custom graphic drawing, then it is quite complex. You must trigger the method to re-draw your control graphic everytime any changes occured in the item list for it to take effect. It will be better if you can do partial update to your graphic (maybe using panels to trick it), but it is harder.

If not handled correctly (moreover if your control contains huge amount of data and/or control size) then it can causes some high memory loads.

Comment: In addition to this, it's worth mentioning that there's no need for "custom drawing" in WPF. Not in the sense of having to code all the thing in C# as in winforms. WPF supports the concept of `ControlTemplates` and also `DataTemplates` which are defined in XAML (much easier and more scalable than winforms' owner draw), also WPF uses retained graphics, so there's no need for you to do any "partial re-draw", the framework takes care of re-layouting and re-rendering by itself whenever a relevant property changes in any UI Element. See DependencyProperty and AffectsRender in MSDN.